# Hdfs find files below certain size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

Is there a way to list files with size less than certain size in Hdfs . Using the command line or even a spark script ? 
Scala / spark would be great as it may run faster as compared to command line .
I have looked at the Apache FileSystem documentation but could not find much information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below command to show files which are more than 1KB

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R / | awk '$5 > 1000'
```

Similarly, you can use the below script to show files of less than 1KB

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R / | awk '$5 < 1000'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is great . Any idea how can we achieve this using spark? The only reason I ask is because if I need to run through large number of files then this method is going to be slow

Comment: If you are just looking for file sizes and nothing more then doing this way would be faster than Spark IMHO.

Comment: I will running thought folders and sub folder having millions of files .

Comment: Do you mean this way is more quicker?   also, SPARK IMHO - what this mean - in memory ?

Comment: Yes, if it just calculating file sizes this should be faster compared to the startup time of a Spark Job. Again though if there are billions of files strategies might change.